# Flutter: dynamic list of widget in variable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I need to move some of my widgets to `List<Widget> _rentCategories`. Right now I have them on a `SliverAppBar` list but I'm adding a reorder feature using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables

If I move my widgets inside a var the ordering works but all my widgets won't have a modifiable state having a static value.

If I do something like this (without having any var) it happens the oposite, the widgets work but not the order (which makes sense because I'm forcing that order):

```
ReorderableSliverList(
              delegate: ReorderableSliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  _showTableCalendar(),
                  _showContact(),
                ],
              ),
              onReorder: _onReorder,
            );
```

How could I have this without losing my state?:

```
List<Widget> _rentCategories = [
                  _showTableCalendar(),
                  _showContact(),
                ];
```

...

```
ReorderableSliverList(
              delegate: ReorderableSliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                     (BuildContext context, int index) => _rentCategories[index],
                   childCount: _rentCategories.length),
              onReorder: _onReorder,
            );
```

PS: I don't mind using a different library for this

Comment: `but all my widgets won't have a modifiable state having a static value`, are you not passing the values via the widget constructors?

Comment: The _rentCategories has exactly the same value as I put for ReorderableSliverChildListDelegate (I also updated the question)